# Android Spinner only selects top value

Tags: android

I've tried this a few different ways and all the code does is print out the top value of the spinner.

```
final String [] equipment=new String[]{//items
  }

ArrayAdapter<?> ad=new ArrayAdapter<Object>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,equipment);
ad.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
Spinner spin=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinneritem);
spin.setAdapter(ad);

int position = spin.getSelectedItemPosition();
final String equipmentitem = equipment[position].toString();
```

From what I can tell that should be able to take the value of the array that the user has selected, but no matter what I select in the list, it only select the first item, and ignores the actual selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to add a listener to the spinner.

```
spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView,
    View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        equipmentitem = equipment[position].toString(); 

    }
   @Override
   public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                                    }
                            });
```

Comment: Agreed: `int position = spin.getSelectedItemPosition();` occurs immediately after the spinner's creation. This means that it will always grab the first index. You want to grab the index AFTER a user selects one. Thus, you need a listener.